# Shortcut url using classic redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am doing a redirection to a path. The php redirection using headers start at `www.example.com` and redirects to `www.example.com/themes/mypage/login.php`. I know `htaccess` can help create a shortcut `url` but that `url` has to be typed in. I have recently achieved this using htaccess but my css and scripts ain't working. How can i solve this?

Comment: You dont need to type in the .htaccess shortened URL. You can use the headers method to redirect.

Comment: My page structure is static. I don't want the user to see my long and complicated url. Can I still use my php headers with a location that points to the long and complicated url and at the same time have the user see a custom created short url?

Comment: Using only redirection I dont think so you will be able to achieve this. You need to write re-write rules in htaccess, to show short URLs to users, and redirect you page to required script / action.

Comment: You are looking for url rewriting at your webserver.

Comment: Will that also mean that I'll maintain my php header location to point to my long and complicated url or to the rewriting short url instead?